# Hide price in transnational email

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p I have managed to hide price using CSS from the frontend, now I want to hide price and order total from transaction email like when a new order email is sent.
How to do that, and which file I have to override in my child theme.

Comment: Hey, you can remove the whole blocks that tell the price, you can create a template in backoffice and apply that one. I you want to keep everything and just remove the price you can modify the block itself before it is sent to the email by using the email_order_set_template_vars_before observer I think, I did that with the payment_html block if you want an example how to use it

Comment: can you elaborate more with example?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the template files used in emails are located at

`/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email`

Copied the `email folder` with all files inside my theme located at

`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Template_Name/Magento_Sales/templates/`

and removed `Price` and `Order Total` from all .phtml files

Now email working perfectly without showing price.

Answer (score 0):

Good you got a solution, I'll leave here an example of what I was saying for reference it might be helpful in the future.
Basically what I did was using a module that is the same as adding a custom variable to email. In this example I edit the payment block in the new order email. It comes in a string so you can edit as a normal string. You can add a new variable if needed.

Something like this (I'll omit the usual registration.php etc etc)

event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
            <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_extra_data_to_transport" instance="Custom\PaymentBlockOverride\Observer\AddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/AddCustomVariable.p

```
<?php

namespace Custom\PaymentBlockOverride\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{  
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
       $transport['payment_html'] /* The block I want to edit */
       /* Do something nice with it */

       $transport['new_variable'] = 'A cool new variable to use in your template'

    }
}
```

Use the new var in email as {{var new_variable}}.

Hope it might help someday :D